# как сделать счетчик в map?

Tags: javascript

как сделать счетчик в map?

получить вот такое `[ '0 ke', '1 ke', '2 l' ]`

```
let array = ['ke', 'ke', 'l']

const newArray = array.map( item => {
    return `${array.indexOf(item)} ${item}`
})

console.log(newArray) // [ '0 ke', '0 ke', '2 l' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let array = ['ke', 'ke', 'l']

const newArray = array.map((item, index) => `${index} ${item}`);

console.log(newArray)
```